# Elasticsearch Multiple Attachment Upload

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use elasticsearch(version 2.33) to look for a string in files,
I tried to create mapping to store multiple files but it always giving me the same error,
here is what I've gone so far:

PUT /messages

PUT /messages/attachment/_mapping

DATA:

```
{
    "attachment": {
        "properties": {
            "my_attachment": {
                "type": "nested",
                "include_in_parent": true,
                "properties": {
                    "attachmentContent": {
                        "type": "attachment",
                        "path": "full",
                        "fields": {
                            "attachmentContent": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets",
                                "store": true
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "attachment_id": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's always giving me the same error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [attachmentContent : {type=string}]"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "Mapping definition for [fields] has unsupported parameters:  [attachmentContent : {type=string}]"
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

tried to follow the instructions here in the comment
http://grokbase.com/t/gg/elasticsearch/148v29ymaf/how-can-we-index-array-of-attachments
and it's not working

appreciate any help, Nevo :)

Comment: Would it be possible to (scrub if needed) and post one line of your input document ?

Comment: Wanted to see what the document being indexed looks like.